# Controller file missing after default installation of CakePHP in Windows 10

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new to this and wanted to check out how a Webframework works. I installed CakePHP via Controller in Windows 10. I am using the Windows IIS7 Server and not W/XAMP. I used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZRP3geT0xo) video and [this](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html) documentation. The only thing I did manually besides letting the Controller install CakePHP was setting up the Rewrite Module 2.0 for IIS7 and creating a web config file as in the description [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#iis7-windows-hosts).

Now, when I access "http://localhost/Verzeichnis/CakePHP/my_app_name/webroot" I get `Error: WebrootController could not be found.`

There is a description under the error: `Create the class WebrootController below in file: src\Controller\WebrootController.php` but I suspect this should be created automatically, right? Also, creating a file with this content brings up other errors that makes me think I should not be forced to do this manually.

`composer update` in my_app_name does work but does not find anything to update.

Comment: why is it your local url is so long?   maybe your root directory is   http://localhost/Verzeichnis/CakePHP

Comment: As I understood the documents the folder webroot contains the actual browser file to load. All other directories just show the directory content in the browser. "Verzeichnis" is the directory I gave to IIS7 as alternative to httpdocs. Afterwards I installed CakePHP into this directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was that I did not run the built-in server of CakePHP. I assumed that I have to use the Windows webserver IIS7. But by running

`cake server`

from the command line in the `bin` folder of the project (in my case `my_app_name`) I could now successfully open the content in the `webroot` folder via the browser.

This is done by using `localhost:8765` (localhost with a different port than the standard port) in the browser.

While this solution worked it would still be interesting to understand what the problem was/is with the Windows ISS7 webserver.

Comment: You can also try the "port" parameter in the console: `cake server -p 80` - 80 is standard http port, and now You can type in browser just `http://localhost`

Answer (score 1):

Webroot indeed is the directory containing index.php which is entry point of application, but you don't need to include it in your url. Rewrite rules that you set are responsible for rewriting requests and pointing them to their destination.

To access your app, you should simply use url pointing to cakephp root folder, which in your case is probably http://localhost/Verzeichnis/CakePHP/my_app_name/